# How to extend the OnTouch behavior of EditText without missing its normal OnTouch behavior?

Tags: android, ontouch

The normal OnTouch behavior of `EditText` is that it gets the focus and becomes ready for typing.
How to extend the OnTouch behavior of `EditText` without affecting its normal OnTouch behavior?

When I try to write code in `onTouch` method, I found that the original normal behavior is missed, and the only behavior is the defined in the method. It is expected but how to keep the original behavior alongside the new extending behavior.

The extending behavior can be something like showing `Toast` or changing the background of the `EditText` and so on.

```
 @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
 {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
      {
         //The original behavior plus the new behavior.
      }
 }
```

Comment: You can call `super().onTouch()` if your logic doesn't handle the click

Answer (score 1):

You should `return false;` — that should be all you need to do.